# console commands not executed while dubug the tizen app

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

When I execute commands in console while app is running in tizen simulator Its working. But when app is running on Samsung smart TV in debug mode, console command are not executed. Please anybody share me the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug it seems in chrome (which is launched by tizen studio for debugging)

I have created a chrome extension that fixes the issue here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tizen-console-fix/hfpknnioheddhjmjhchindnmcoadmekl?hl=en

install it on chrome on the machine you are using to debug. Please let me know if it works for you.